# Lydian Guitar Voicing (Maj7 #4 Chord)

Tags: guitar, theory, chords, chord-theory, jazz

From the fourth mode (Lydian) of the major scale (in C) we get `F G A B C D E F`. In jazz, it appears the fifth is often omitted and the #4 takes over in place of it. This results in `F A B E`, the root, maj 3rd, tritone, and the seventh.

I have found one voicing on guitar so far that sounds good for this:

e -> 0

B -> 0

G -> 2

D -> 3

A -> x

E -> x

Are there any with the root on the `A` or `Low E`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you allow the upper notes to scramble, other voicings appear. For example, a few of them are:

- R-7M-3-♯11.

GMaj7(♯11) = 3x442x

CMaj7(♯11) = x3x452

- R-♯11-7M-3

CMaj7(♯11) = x3445x

- R-3-♯11-7M (your example, which is almost impossible to play in upper strings as you noticed)

GMaj7(♯11) = xx5422

(Although I called the interval a ♯11 and not ♯4, since there are no 9ths and 5ths in my examples, in practice they are the same thing as the Maj7(♯4) chords you describe)

Comment: Yeah, I use #4 and #11 interchangeably, but not sure if I should. Also, really like `CMaj7(♯11) = x3445x`. Sounds sooo Diablo I

Comment: Yeah, because the tritone is evident in two adjacent voices and they are in the low register. Not very jazzy :) When dealing with a chord, you want a ♯11 and not a ♯4. A 4 replaces the 3, unless you write "add4". 11 is probably what you want, but it comes with the possibility of a 9.

Comment: so this chord should omit the 3 and 5 and be root 4 7 11 13?

Comment: I don't get the reasoning in your comment, but the notation Cmaj7(♯11) implies: R 3 5 7M 9 ♯11. However, it's customary (but not required) to omit certain notes in these extended chords. The 5 and the 9 would be the first options (the 3, 7 and the extensions you really want and write, in this case ♯11, can't be excluded). If I see a  Cmaj7(4) I would believe it's a misspelled Cmaj7(sus4). I believe Cmaj7(♯4) would be seen as a misspelled Cmaj7(♯11), although the logic makes me see a Cmaj7(sus♯4). People might have different meanings to certain notations apart from the "correct standard".